# Django test error. Migrations fail during django test; django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing, django-tests

I have a django app which has not been tested lately. I have to run a custom command. I have written a test for it and run all migrations.

I was able to successfully run all migrations.I'm able to run the command and my app works as excepted.

But when I tried to run the django test then the following error was thrown.

```
python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_ILIDD_db" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_ILIDD_db', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "auth_group" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 39, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\test_without_migrations\management\commands\_base.py", line 78, in handle
    super(CommandMixin, self).handle(*test_labels, **options)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 684, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 604, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 169, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py", line 67, in create_test_db
    call_command(
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 168, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 202, in handle
    self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 340, in sync_apps
    self.stdout.write("    Running deferred SQL...\n")
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 115, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\nlp-ilidd-processor\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist
```

I tried to run migrate auth seperately. There were no migrations to apply

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: auth
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` ?

Comment: Django's suggested way of doing migration is to commit the migration files( all developers commit the migration files) and which make sure all the developer system, staging, prod have the same migrations files...make the migration process smoother and conflict free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my question I was able to run the migrations successfully and was able to run my django app as well. But when I tried to run the tests the above mentioned error occurred.

I solved the issue by mirroring my db by editing `settings.py` or (`local_settings.py`).
Now I am able to run the test without any migration issues.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'TEST': {
            'MIRROR': 'default',
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following django-app help to run django tests without affecting the migration conflicts.

Install 'django-test-without-migrations'

```
pip install django-test-without-migrations
```

add it  it in INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'test_without_migrations',
)
```

Then run,

```
python manage.py test --nomigrations
```

--nomigrations make sure your tests won't fail due to the migrations issues.

Refer: https://pypi.org/project/django-test-without-migrations/

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py makemigrations auth
```

then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```